# XML to check conditions and ouput tags, PYTHON

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file as shown below:

```
   <records>
   <record>
        <device_serial_number>PAD203146024</device_serial_number>
        <device_serial_number_2>203146024</device_serial_number_2>
        <docsis_mac>6412695EB9BB</docsis_mac>
   </record>
   <record>
        <device_serial_number>PAD206024</device_serial_number>
        <device_serial_number_2>20324</device_serial_number_2>
        <docsis_mac>6412BB</docsis_mac>
   </record>
   </records>
```

I read this xml file using ETree in python and works well, now I want to check if  tag has text starting with "PAD" if it has then output it as below:

```
    Expected output
    <record>
    <device_serial_number>PAD203146024</device_serial_number>
    <device_serial_number_2>203146024</device_serial_number_2>
    <docsis_mac>6412695EB9BB</docsis_mac>
    </record>
```

Comment: *I read this xml file using ETree* - it would be nice if you have shown that code

Comment: added my sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

recs=[ET.tostring(c) for c in record if c.find('device_serial_number').text[:3]=='PAD']
for rec in recs:
   print(rec)
```

where `record` above is `record` element in the for loop as shown in your question. This should return your records **only if** `'device_serial_number'` starts with `PAD` as below:-

```
<record>
        <device_serial_number>PAD203146024</device_serial_number>
        <device_serial_number_2>203146024</device_serial_number_2>
        <docsis_mac>6412695EB9BB</docsis_mac>
   </record>

<record>
        <device_serial_number>PAD206024</device_serial_number>
        <device_serial_number_2>20324</device_serial_number_2>
        <docsis_mac>6412BB</docsis_mac>
   </record>
```

If any of the record elements do not have `device_serial_number` as a child then I would use the below:

```
   from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
   from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

   tree = ET.parse('C:\\Use\\CO.xml')
   root = tree.getroot()
   for record in root.findall('records'):
       recs=[c for c in t if c.find('device_serial_number')!=None and c.find('device_serial_number').text[:3]=='PAD']
       for rec in recs:
          print(parseString(ET.tostring(rec)).toprettyxml(''))
```

Comment: recs=[ET.tostring(c) for c in record if c.find('device_serial_number').text[:3]=='PAD']                         AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: hey did you put this in the for loop?

Comment: may be some of your `record` elements to not have `device_serial_number`?

Comment: if so I will put a check for that let me know

Comment: this works and can you tell me a way where i can print everything inside the tags i.e just print all the content inside the <record>tag

Comment: can you update the question with expected output? For me everything is inside the `<record>....</record>` as shown in my answer. I'm unable to visualize what your requirement is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155459/discussion-between-bulbus-and-user8521874).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help, appreciate it